# Арм кросс компилятор с libc 2.11

Tags: libc, c, arm, c++

Пожалуйста, подскажите, где можно найти арм кросс компилятор идущий с libс от 2.11 до 2.14?

Answer (score 1):

Самый лучший вариант - собрать самому с помощью crosstool-ng.